# Strong Password Checker (Python)

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, strings, regex

#### Problem

Write a program to return `True`, if a string is a strong password.

---

A password is considered strong if below conditions are all met:

- It should have at least 6 characters and at most 20 characters.
- It must contain at least one lowercase, one uppercase and one digit.
- It must NOT contain three repeating characters in a row ("...aaa..." is weak, but "...aa...a..." is fine, assuming other conditions are met).

#### Code

I've solved a similar problem to [LeetCode Strong Password Checker](https://leetcode.com/problems/strong-password-checker/). If you would like to review the code or add other methods or provide any change/improvement recommendations please do so! Thank you!

```
def strong_password_match(s: str) -> bool:
    """Returns a boolean if a password is correct"""
    import re
    if re.match(
            r'^(?!.*([a-z])\1\1)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{6,20}$', s) is not None:
        return True
    return False


def strong_password_search(s: str) -> bool:
    """Returns a boolean if a password is correct"""
    import re
    if re.search(
            r'^(?!.*([a-z])\1\1)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{6,20}$', s) is not None:
        return True
    return False


def strong_password_findall(s: str) -> bool:
    """Returns a boolean if a password is correct"""
    import re
    if re.findall(
            r'^(?!.*([a-z])\1\1)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{6,20}$', s) != []:
        return True

    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ---------------------------- TEST ---------------------------
    import timeit
    import cProfile

    DIVIDER_DASH_LINE = '-' * 50
    GREEN_APPLE = '\U0001F34F'
    RED_APPLE = '\U0001F34E'

    test_methods = (
        ("re.match", strong_password_match),
        ("re.search", strong_password_search),
        ("re.findall", strong_password_findall),
    )

    test_inputs = ('abcAb1', 'abcAb1abcAb1abcAb100',
                   'abcAb1abcAb1abcAb10111', 'aaaAb1abcAb1abcAb100')

    # --------------------------------- PROFILING AND BANCHMARK SETTINGS --------------------------------------
    NUMBER_OF_RUNS = 1
    CPROFILING_ON = False
    BENCHMARK_ON = True

    for description, method in test_methods:
        print((GREEN_APPLE + RED_APPLE) * 5)

        for test_input in test_inputs:
            if CPROFILING_ON:
                print(f'{description} cProfiling: ', cProfile.run("method(test_input)"))
            if BENCHMARK_ON:
                print(f'{description} Benchmark: ', timeit.Timer(
                    f'for i in range({NUMBER_OF_RUNS}): {method(test_input)}', 'gc.enable()').timeit())

            if method(test_input):
                print(f'{GREEN_APPLE} {description}: "{test_input}" is a strong password.')
            else:
                print(f'{RED_APPLE} {description}: "{test_input}" is not a strong password.')
```

#### Output

```
re.match Benchmark:  1.8437564770000001
 re.match: "abcAb1" is a strong password.
re.match Benchmark:  1.9900512190000006
 re.match: "abcAb1abcAb1abcAb100" is a strong password.
re.match Benchmark:  1.782858269
 re.match: "abcAb1abcAb1abcAb10111" is not a strong password.
re.match Benchmark:  1.8016775740000002
 re.match: "aaaAb1abcAb1abcAb100" is not a strong password.

re.search Benchmark:  1.8374795240000008
 re.search: "abcAb1" is a strong password.
re.search Benchmark:  1.8352807049999988
 re.search: "abcAb1abcAb1abcAb100" is a strong password.
re.search Benchmark:  1.8023251919999996
 re.search: "abcAb1abcAb1abcAb10111" is not a strong password.
re.search Benchmark:  1.9213070860000006
 re.search: "aaaAb1abcAb1abcAb100" is not a strong password.

re.findall Benchmark:  1.7806425130000019
 re.findall: "abcAb1" is a strong password.
re.findall Benchmark:  1.836686480000001
 re.findall: "abcAb1abcAb1abcAb100" is a strong password.
re.findall Benchmark:  1.8053996060000017
 re.findall: "abcAb1abcAb1abcAb10111" is not a strong password.
re.findall Benchmark:  1.8203372360000003
 re.findall: "aaaAb1abcAb1abcAb100" is not a strong password.
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OHLPNG/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/OHLPNG/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Source

[Strong Password Checker](https://leetcode.com/problems/strong-password-checker/)

Comment: ugh... I vehemently object to the LeetCode challenge for having a really crappy definition of "strong password". [These are good guidelines.](https://spycloud.com/new-nist-guidelines/). Rules #1 and #2 actually make your passwords worse and less safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Imports

I notice you import `re` *three* times, once for each password check function. Why?  Just import the library once at the top of the file, and you can use it in all of your functions.

## Returning Booleans

Instead of returning `True` or `False` based on the result of the expression, simply return the expression. It results to a boolean anyway, so returning `True` and `False` is unnecessary; just return the expression.

## DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)

You have three functions that essentially perform the same task, just with *very slightly* different function calls. You can compress these regex checks into one method. Then you can pass what type of check you want to perform on the password. See below.

```
import re

def strong_password_check(password: str, type_of_check: str) -> bool:
    """
    Accepts a password and the type of check to perform on the password

    :param password: Password to check
    :param type_of_check: How to check the password. Has to be "match", "search", or "findall"

    """
    regex = r'^(?!.*([a-z])\1\1)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{6,20}$'
    if type_of_check == "match":
        return re.match(regex, password) is not None
    if type_of_check == "search":
        return re.search(regex, password) is not None
    if type_of_check == "findall":
        return re.findall(regex, password) != []
```

## Test Cases

Not really sure the usefulness of red and green apples. Again, importing `cProfile` and `timeit` should go at the top of the program.

I see you're checking for performance, but not for the actual strength of the password. Would your program agree that `Password123` is a good password? Any security professional worth his salt wouldn't agree.

I suggest that you use the [Kolmgorov Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) to check the strength of the password.